# How to validate an email string using bool

Tags: c#, function, validation, email

Trying to follow an example from a site that I saw. I know I have the function right but not sure how to implement it correctly into the `Main`. Also very inexperienced so please bear with me.

```
namespace TextSystemString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your email.");
            string UserEmail = Console.ReadLine();
            string ValEmail = IsValidEmail(UserEmail); 
        }

        static public bool IsValidEmail(string email)
        {
            try
            {
                var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `IsValidEmail` returns a `bool`, but you are trying to assign it to a `string`. You likely just need, `if (IsValidEmail(UserEmail)) { do stuff with the valid email } else { tell user the email is invalid }`. Using exception handling to determine if an email is valid or not is another discussion..

Answer (score 1):

Your `IsValidEmail` function returns a bool.

In `Main()`, you have to declare and set a boolean variable, not a string - which is why your app is not compiling. You can then do whatever you want with the variable.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter your email.");
   string UserEmail = Console.ReadLine();
   bool ValEmail = IsValidEmail(UserEmail); 

   Console.WriteLine("Valid Email:{0}", ValEmail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is if you are using a more recent version of VS and C# is that you can use `var`.

> **[var (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)**
>
> Beginning in Visual C# 3.0, variables that are declared at method
>   scope can have an implicit type **`var`**. An implicitly typed local
>   variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type
>   yourself, but the compiler determines the type.
>
> The following two declarations of i are functionally equivalent:
>
> ```
> var i = true; // implicitly typed
> bool i = false; //explicitly typed
> ```

Which result in your code being refactored to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your email.");
    var userEmail = Console.ReadLine(); // implicitly typed as string
    var isValidEmail = IsValidEmail(userEmail); // implicitly typed as bool

    Console.WriteLine("Valid Email:{0}", isValidEmail);
}
```

Since your `IsValidEmail` function returns a `bool`, then the compiler will determine that the type of the `isValidEmail` is implicitly typed as `bool` thus avoiding compiler issues as the compiler determines the type for you.